# Android Studio table layout how to

Tags: android-studio, android-tablelayout

I am new to android app developing. And I am trying to make an application that displays daily routines of my classes. I have already made 75% of the application but I am stuck in the last 25%. I just cant make the table like in the picture. Please help me.

[image: table layout]

[image: required table layout]

Comment: Hi Utsav, what you need in table cells EditText's or textView's?

Comment: Do you want only text view in our table cells?

Comment: is there a reason why there is no difference in the 2 pictures?

Answer (score -1):

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@color/gray">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@color/gray"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="20dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:background="@color/gray"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@mipmap/bus" />
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>

<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/origen"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/gray"
    android:orientation="vertical">
 <TableRow
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_ponit_origdin"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Tapo"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"/>
 </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_ponit_origin"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Ciudad de Mexico"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"/>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.Space
    android:layout_width="15dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp" />
<TableRow
    android:layout_width="20dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@mipmap/transfer" />
</TableRow>

<android.support.v4.widget.Space
    android:layout_width="15dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp" />
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="20dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:background="@color/gray"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@mipmap/bus" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/destino"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/gray"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_ponit_destino"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Veracruz"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"/>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_ponit_two_destino"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Veracruz, Ver."
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"/>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>


<android.support.v4.widget.Space
    android:layout_width="15dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp" />


<TableRow
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_departure_time"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="12:00"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/white"/>
</TableRow>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_inf_exit"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:text="Salida:"
                android:textSize="10sp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_exit"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="02 Mar 2017"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="10sp"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_inf_places_sold"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/plases_sold"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="10sp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_places_sold"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="42"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="10sp"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_info_race_number"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/race_number"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="10sp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_race_number"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="20000"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="10sp" />

        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

**I had a problem similar to yours and I did it, I hope it will work for you.**

Comment: Describe the action of your code at the top, please.